# how can I subtract each element by one to generate a list contains all zeros i tried to solve it in recursive way

Tags: python, subtraction

if I have a list how can I subtract each element by one in a recursive way ??I implemented this code

```
list=[5,4,3,2,1,1]
level=numbers[0]

def list_arrays(numb):
    if len(numbers)-1 < level:
      print("nograph")
   else:
     for i in range(len(numbers)):
       numbers[i] = numbers[i] - 1
         print(numbers)
```

the output should  be like this

```
> [4,3,2,1,0,0]
> [3,2,1,0,0,0]
> [2,1,0,0,0,0]
> [1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

but its printed only the first array

```
> [4,3,2,1,0,0]
```

Comment: You'll need to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: What have you tried?  We’re not going to do it for you (unless you come across a rep hound). Tip, write the algorithm on *paper*, then implement the steps in code.

Comment: idid but its not working i will post it

Comment: You mean "subtract each *non-zero* element by one", correct?

Comment: Aside, these are `lists` *not* arrays, very different things.  `arrays` tag removed.

Comment: i updated the code yes i mean lists

Comment: Do you want to iteratively subtract one to the initial list, in this case [5,4,3,2,1], until the list has zeros, such that if the value is zero then the algorithm will not subtract a one to that value thus ending with a [0,0,0,0,0], because that is just a recursive algorithm, let me know if that is the case, and that should be very easy to implement

Comment: yes it must be recursively implemented but it only prints the first list  not the entire soultion

Comment: "it must be recursively implemented".  Your posted code is not recursive.

Comment: Why does it **have** to be recursive?

Comment: can you help me to do it recursive way?

Comment: I have provided an answer that is functionally correct. If you can explain why it **has** to be recursive then I'm sure someone will help you

Comment: I'm trying to build a graph with natural numbers in which the degree of each edge should be exactly  the same of the number of the degrees,,,, every pair of nodes should not contain a loop

Comment: Recursion involves looping inasmuch as the (recursive) function will be called repeatedly in some controlled manner - e.g., *for*, *while*. Also, your first attempt at the code involves a *for* loop. I think I smell homework

Comment: You don't really need recursion.  A comprehension can do that easily and not be limited by maximum depth:  `L = [5,4,3,2,1,1]`
`[ [max(0,n-i-1) for n in L] for i in range(max(L)) ]` --> `[[4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0],[3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

l=[5,4,3,2,1,1]
arr = np.array(l)

# loop until all elements are 0
while not np.all((arr == 0)):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        # subtract non-zero element by 1
        if not arr[i] == 0:
            arr[i] -= 1 
    print(arr)
```

output:

```
> [4 3 2 1 0 0] 
> [3 2 1 0 0 0] 
> [2 1 0 0 0 0] 
> [1 0 0 0 0 0] 
> [0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Do you think maybe *numpy* is a bit overkill for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
list_ = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]

while any(list_):
    print(list_)
    list_ = list(map(lambda x: max(0, x-1), list_))
```

Comment: https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference It looks like numpy array has better performance than list.

Comment: @christophan Sorry, I missed the performance requirement in the original question. I assume you timed both mine and JayPeerachai's answers. What were the results?

Comment: @christophan I've done some timing (I couldn't resist). 100 thousand iterations of my answer executes on 0.74s. The numpy based solution takes 3.46s. Happy to share the code with you if you like